# Send clone items with javascript in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

my idea is create a order form. i created the form and i used a javascript to clone the fields products and quantity for the customer click and create a new field to select a new product if they want. that way he can select many products he wants. the problem is that i don`t know how to send this information that was cloned using php to email.
follow my code:

```js
function addInput(divName) {
  var copy = document.getElementById('forclone').cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(copy);
}
```

```html
<form method="post" id="onlineorder" action="sendform.php">
  <fieldset id="listproducts">
    <legend>PRODUCTS</legend>
    <div id='forclone'>
      <select name="product" id="product">
        <optgroup label="PRODUCT 1">
          <option>PRODUCT 1 - BLUE</option>
          <option>PRODUCT 1 - RED</option>
          <option>PRODUCT 1 - YELLOW</option>
        </optgroup>

        <optgroup label="PRODUCT 2">
          <option>PRODUCT 2 - WHITE</option>
          <option>PRODUCT 2 - BLACK</option>
          <option>PRODUCT 2 - GRAY</option>
        </optgroup>


      </select>

      &nbsp;
      <label for="quantity">Quantity:<span style="color:red">*</span>
      </label>&nbsp;
      <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" placeholder="Qnt" min="0" max="9999" required/>
    </div>

    <div id="dynamicinput"></div>
    <input type="button" value="New Product" onclick="addInput('dynamicinput');" />
  </fieldset>
  <p></p>
  <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

PHP (sendform.php)

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



$email_to = "email@domain.com";

$email_subject = "[ Online Order ]";


function died($error) {


    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

    echo $error."<br /><br />";

    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

    die();

}



if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||

    !isset($_POST['business']) ||

    !isset($_POST['email']) ||

    !isset($_POST['phone']) ||

    !isset($_POST['quantity']) ||

    !isset($_POST['product'])) {

    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');

}



$name = $_POST['name']; // required

$business = $_POST['business']; // required

$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

$phone = $_POST['phone']; // not required

$quantity = $_POST['quantity']; // required

$product = $_POST['product']; // not required



$error_message = "";

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}


if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

}

$email_message = "<strong>You received an online order. <br>Follow below the informations.</strong><br><br>\n\n";



function clean_string($string) {

    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

}



$email_message .= "<br><strong>Name: </strong>".clean_string($name)."\n";

$email_message .= "<br><strong>Business: </strong>".clean_string($business)."\n";

$email_message .= "<br><strong>Email: </strong>".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

$email_message .= "<br><strong>Phone: </strong>".clean_string($phone)."\n";

$email_message .= "<br><br><strong>ORDER: </strong>\n";

$email_message .= "<br><br><strong>Qty: </strong>".clean_string($quantity)."\n";

$email_message .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Product: </strong>".clean_string($product)."\n";





$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset= UTF-8 \r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

?>


<p>Thank you for order. We will contact you as soon as possible.</p>
<p>You can close this page now.</p>


<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: specify the name attribute of select tag as array like name="prod[]" and on server you can read that array...

Comment: i am sorry but i am new, could you be more specific?

Comment: hey...what i mean is in your HTML name your select element as say "product[]" and then in your php you can read it as an array as php will automatically make array out of it and you can read it... [i will add a sample]

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to change the name of the cloned node's items into some increment of a number, such as `product1`, `product2`, etc. and put them into a for loop for the email.
For example(this is untested):

```
$email = '';
for($i = 1; isset($_POST['product'.$i]); $i+=1){
  $email .= $_POST['product'.$i];
}
$email_message .= $email;
```

All you have to do is keep a running tally of the amount of clones done in javascript, and append that number to the end of the name.

```
var runningproducttally = 1;

function addInput(divName) {
   var copy = document.getElementById('forclone').cloneNode(true);
   var select1 = copy.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
   select1.setAttribute("name","product"+runningproducttally);
   document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(copy);
   runningproducttally++;
}
```

Comment: Hey alex, thanks for trying to help me. I used this idea but it didn't work. They didn`t send the new products.

Comment: it didnt send my new products. didnt apper an error. is it right?  'function addInput(divName) {'
            'var copy =document.getElementById('forclone').cloneNode(true);
            document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(copy);
            var select1 = copy.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
            select1.setAttribute("name","product"+runningproducttally);'

Comment: You append the elements to the DOM before you change the name of the element inside the clone. I'll update my answer with a more complete version.

Comment: I put it here to make it easier to see. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/evandrosx/nzqm37p5/)

Comment: worked, the form sent the select information, but i need that go with the number of the quantity and it arrive there organized, because they arrive there all together.

Comment: It's essentially the same thing, and you can have it in the same for loop too. You just replace select with input in JS

Comment: Please mark the appropriate answer as the solution if the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have used your code for demo:
In your HTML :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addInput(divName) {
      var copy = document.getElementById('forclone').cloneNode(true);
      document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(copy);
    }
</script>

<form method="post" id="onlineorder" action="sendform.php">
          <fieldset id="listproducts">
            <legend>PRODUCTS</legend>
            <div id='forclone'>
              <select name="product" id="product[]">
                <optgroup label="PRODUCT 1">
                  <option>PRODUCT 1 - BLUE</option>
                  <option>PRODUCT 1 - RED</option>
                  <option>PRODUCT 1 - YELLOW</option>
                </optgroup>

                <optgroup label="PRODUCT 2">
                  <option>PRODUCT 2 - WHITE</option>
                  <option>PRODUCT 2 - BLACK</option>
                  <option>PRODUCT 2 - GRAY</option>
                </optgroup>


              </select>

              &nbsp;
              <label for="quantity">Quantity:<span style="color:red">*</span>
              </label>&nbsp;
              <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" placeholder="Qnt" min="0" max="9999" required/>
            </div>

            <div id="dynamicinput"></div>
            <input type="button" value="New Product" onclick="addInput('dynamicinput');" />
          </fieldset>
          <p></p>
          <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
        </form>
```

in you PHP sendform.php :

```
$products = $_REQUEST['product'];
```